# "logical constant" vs "logical variable"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I'm learning introduction to logic on coursera offered by Michael Genesereth with Stanford University, where the the course used the term "logical constant" to denote a proposition sentence.

For example:
If it is raining, then it is cold. Using letter r to represent it is raining, and using letter c to represent it is cold, then the sentence changed to r→c, where r and c are called logical constant which could be allocated with True and false value.

My confusion is, instead of logical constant, wouldn't it be more appropriate to call r and c logical variable, since their value could replaced by any human language proposition or logical value True and false.

Answer (score 3):

In first order logics, true and false are not values that are taken on by bound or free variables.  If you have a background in software this may be confusing since you can store true/false into variables just as easily as storing integers or strings.

So if you have an expression like $$\forall x ~ P(x)$$
then $P$ holds for every object in the domain of discourse.  But true/false are not objects in the universe (in first order logics), so you cannot infer $P(\top)$ or $P(\bot)$.  That is why there is a grammatical distinction between operators (boolean to boolean), relations (universe to boolean), and functions (universe to universe).  So your author is distinguishing between free variables that take on values from the universe and so called "logical constants" that take on values of true or false.

Aside, this distinction does not exist logics like untyped lambda calculus.  In those, true/false and natural numbers are both represented using the same grammatical rules.

Comment: Couln't thanks you more. Everything makes sense except for the part  where you said, if I understand correctly, relations is connection between universe and boolean. If I'm not wrong, from the book here: http://logic.stanford.edu/intrologic/secondary/notes/chapter_03.html relations includes logical equivalence, entailment and consistency. a→b is equivalent to ¬a ∨ b.  Isn't it boolean to boolean?

Comment: That page is using strange vocabulary, but at least they say "relationship" rather than "relation".  A relation is what I described above.  For example, "even" is a relation:  it input a natural number and output "true" or "false" depending on whether the number is even.  $\ge$ is also a relation, it inputs 2 objects and outputs true or false.

Comment: Thanks so much. I felt more doors are opened with light by your comment. I'm more interested in the philosophy of logic but courses I have taken (both in college and online) are more practical i.e.focusing on using of logic rather than examine the nature of logic.  I wondered what place I might go for knowledge which are  more philosophical such as the sort in you comment? Links books articles are appreciated :p

Comment: In the next few decades, as software designers take logic away from the university math students, I think such treatment of logic will be much more common.  For now, you'll probably just have to endure.  Perhaps try out here: http://www.logicmatters.net/